# How to click on mat-select-trigger when mat-select dropdown panel is open?

Tags: angular, mat-select

<mat-select-trigger (click)="triggerFirst($event)">
{{ placeholder }}
<span *ngIf="selectedDropdownlist.length"> {{ placeholder ? ' - ' : '' }}{{ getList() }}
<span (mousedown)="$event.stopPropagation();showTooltip($event)">{{getCountOfItems()}}

I have large number of options in mat-selct and i want to display them in custom tooltip when i click on count in mat-select-trigger.
This is working fine when dropdown panel is close but when dropdown panel is open clicking on count which is shown is mat-select-trigger , mat-selct dropdown panel gets closed.
How can i achieve the functionality of clicking on count to show tooltip when dropdown panel is open?

I have large number of options in mat-selct and i want to display them in custom tooltip when i click on count in mat-select-trigger.
This is working fine when dropdown panel is close but when dropdown panel is open clicking on count which is shown is mat-select-trigger , mat-selct dropdown panel gets closed.
How can i achieve the functionality of clicking on count to show tooltip when dropdown panel is open?